# Is "smackerel" made up by Winnie-the-Pooh?

Tags: etymology

That silly old bear is often talking about having, or downright having, a "smackerel" of honey.

Is this word made up for the Winnie-the-Pooh universe, or a "real" word? Is it similar to some previous word?

Comment: Did you look it up?

Comment: The lack of any definition offered by dictionaries other than UD, and its presence in the famous work of fiction, seems to indicate that it is a nonce-word. hardly in common currency, though understood by all and used by some Winnie fans.

Answer (score -1):

"**Smackerel**" is an invented word produced by the combination of "Smack" and "Mackerel" - Mackerel is included for humorous effect.

OED:

> **Smack n. A taste, tinge, or suggestion.**
>
> 1. a. A taste or flavour; the distinctive or peculiar taste of something, or a special flavour distinguishable from this.

Rice pudding with a smack of cinnamon

> 3.a. transferred. A trace, tinge, or suggestion of something specified.
>
> 1874   F. C. Burnand My Time xxix. 280   A smack of real earnestness in his tone.

Thus smack - a small sample of something

Also

> **Mackerel - a type of fish.**
>
> 1904   E. Tregear Maori Race 107   Mackerel were prepared by being cleaned inside and washed with salt water.

Comment: You shouldn't say that you're including *mackerel* for humorous effect if it's an essential part of the definition—as you claim it is. But, more than that, what actual evidence do you have that the word was invented through the combination of these two words? This answer, at it stands, is a completely unsupported assumption.

Comment: I don't think that it is any part of the definition and have not claimed it to be - it is a humorous parallel that would not have been missed by a child at the time of writing. Rathan D asked *Is it similar to some previous word?*

Comment: I'm questioning your assertion in the first sentence of your answer. You're making an assumption, but you haven't provided any actual support for it. In fact, if you look at the results of Ngram Ngram Viewer when querying the word, you'll see that it has more use than just in *Winnie the Pooh*. And if you follow those links, you might actually find evidence that proves or disproves your unsupported supposition that *it is an invented word produced by the combination of "Smack" and "Mackerel."*

Comment: @JasonBassford *I'm questioning your assertion in the first sentence of your answer.* You should not do that. Rather you should look at the examples in Ngrams, and see that "smackerel" is an OCR reading error for "mackerel". In Google Books, "Philological Quarterly" - Volume 9 - 1930 - Page 158 has only a snippet view but does say  "... does not consider a “portmanteau” word; tritical, brunch, blog, smog, various trade-coinages such as Nabisco, Socony, and Tydol; charadical, ačrobatics, Squirradical, smackerel, smubtle. Motorcade, electrocute, slantindicular, gasolier ..."

Comment: Of course I can question it—because you haven't provided any evidence one way or the other. If I were to claim that the world will end tomorrow, why should anybody just take my word for it? If you take these comments, expand on them, and put them into your answer, then your answer will be more than just a simple assertion. You can say that your answer is "self evident," but that's a matter of opinion.